# What is the proper front end jack point for a 2005 Pontiac Vibe?

Tags: pontiac, jack, jack-stand, vibe

I want to use a floor jack to raise the front end of my 2005 Pontiac Vibe, so I can place jack stands on the pinch welds for an oil change.  Where is a safe place to jack up the front of the vehicle with a floor jack?

[image: 2005 Pontiac Vibe front end]

Is the circled area in red a safe place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the rusty bolt at the top-center of the image. This puts it closer to the front and you won't be putting as much weight on your lifting point. While where you put the circle can probably take the increased load, it would be quite a bit more, considering it is closer to the center of the vehicle. The forward most of the two bolts which are attached to subframe should be a good lift point, because it will be solid there.

Comment: Please excuse my ignorance, but which bolts on my picture attach the subframe to the body?

Comment: @KyleL - Sorry, I made a mistake ... I was thinking incorrectly, but the bolt is still a good lift point. I realize since you said that it doesn't attach to the body. Please see my edits.

Comment: No worries.  I didn't mean to imply those bolts don't attach to the body.  I'm just ignorant of this and don't know how to tell!